# Why won't my for-loop match any of my defined regular expressions?

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, printing

We have just started to learn about regular expressions, but I'm not able to find any matches in my string when I try to use the regex to search. What am I doing wrong?

I created six separate strings (just for the look of it), and concatenated them into one and then i try to loop through the words in the split string and search for one of the regexes i declared

Below, I translated the string, on the right side, just so you know what it says.

```
myString1 = "Skal vi moetes neste torsdag?" # - Shall we meet next Thursday 
myString2 = "Hva med aa heller moetes mandag?" # - How about Monday
myString3 = "Hvordan gikk moetet forrige mandag?" # - How did the meeting on monday go?
myString4 = "Det gikk bra, vi skal moetes igjen tirsdag onsdag fredag lørdag søndag 13. september." # - It went well, we are meeting again on Sunday September 13th.
myString5 = "Altsaa, 13/09/2014?" 
myString6 = "Ja, Sunday 13. september 2014." # - Yes, Sunday, September 13th 2014

myStringAll = (myString1 + myString2 + myString3 + myString4 + myString5 + myString6)
myWords = myStringAll.split()

regWeekDays = re.compile(r'^(man|tirs|ons|tors|fre|lør|søn)dag$', re.IGNORECASE)
regNextLast = re.compile(r'^[neste].$', re.IGNORECASE)
regDay = re.compile(r'^([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$')
regYear = re.compile(r'^([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])$')

for words in myWords:
    matches = re.findall(regNextLast, words)
    if matches:
        print words
```

Comment: The meaning of `r'^[neste].$'` is to match any of the characters 'n', 'e', 's', 't' followed by another character. I think you haven't really understood regexes.

Comment: Careful: you are defining byte strings in source and didn't specify an encoding. If you are loading your strings from a file, you'll also be loading encoded byte strings, and there is no guarantees that the regular expression will contain bytes in the same codec. Use Unicode values instead; see http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html. Declare your source code codec, use unicode values and decode file contents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with your regular expressions, but the main one is that you use `^` and `$` at the beginning and end of each expression. `^` means to match the beginning of the string and `$` matches the end of a string. Unless your strings are strictly the length of the expressions, `findall` won't match anything.

**An Example**:

```
In [55]: re.findall(r'^a$', 'abcdefghijkl')
Out[55]: [] # "a" is not matched!
```

`^` and `$` should only be used to explicitly match the beginning and end of a string, respectively (or the end of a line in some cases, see the [documentation](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/re.html)). Strip these out and your expressions should start matching.

Here are some more specific problems:

- In `^(man|tirs|ons|tors|fre|lør|søn)dag$` only the first part (`man|tirs|ons|tors|fre|lør|søn`) will be captured and returned by findall. Change this to  a [*non capturing group*](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#non-capturing-and-named-groups) so that the entire expression is returned:
   `(?:man|tirs|ons|tors|fre|lør|søn)dag`
- In `^[neste].$`, I assume you want to capture the string `"neste"`. Currently you have a set `[neste]` which will match *one* of the following characters: `n`, `e`, `s`, or `t`. Change this to simply `neste`. 
  The documentation on sets can be found [here](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#matching-characters).
- `^([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$` is mostly fine, aside from the `^` and `$`, you can omit the hyphen between `0` and `1`, exclude the parentheses, and use the digit symbol `\d` (equivalent to `[0-9]`, however: 
  `[0-2]\d|3[01]`
- Finally in `'^([1-2][0-9][0-9][0-9])$'`, (again, aside from the `^` and `$`) the expression should work as expected, but you *can* make it more succinct. You can use the [curly bracket syntax](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#repeating-things) to specify repeats. Thus a string matching any year from 1000-2999 becomes:
  `[12]\d{3}`

I recommend that you peruse the [HOWTO on Regular Expressions](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html).

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't what was wrong to the point, but you helped me find the error.

Answer (score 1):

`r'^[neste].$'` is probably not what you meant.  This regular expression looks for a string two characters in length where the first character is `in ('e', 'n', 's', 't')` followed by any other single character.  None of the two-character substrings you've split out of your larger string match this pattern.

Maybe you could benefit from a tutorial: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html